# How do I manage multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've spent a few days trying to figure this out, and I also have the O'Reilly Java Threads book. I still haven't figured this out:

I'm running RHEL Linux 6 and Java 6.

When my program starts, I want to loop through the open Listen ports.  For each one, I want to launch a thread that will listen for syn packets, then update a database with tcp/ip and process information every time someone or something tries to connect to that port.

Perhaps I have the idea of threads wrong.  I am expecting some sort of socket like array that gives me some sort of way to manage the threads.

For example, I launch a thread to monitor port 8561, but then it has an error.  I might want to check something for 8561 when it got an error and ended, try again, or something.  How do I know what thread that was when it ended?

Thank you!

Comment: What was the error that you were getting and can you post a code snippet? We can't help you without more information.

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Comment: If you are opening a new channel in a thread without closing previous channel with same address/port, it can give error. You can use signals or threadpools.

Comment: Typically, attempting to micro-manage threads ends badly.  For multiple, parallel network requests, submitting request objects to a threadpool queue, where the number of threads is either fixed or managed by the threadpool class, is hugely safer than attempting to manage thread handles in an array.

Comment: My question may be a simple misunderstanding since I'm new to Java and I may be comparing to other languages.

Comment: My question may be a simple misunderstanding since I'm new to Java and I may be comparing to other languages.  I don't have code that works or fails since I am in the design stage and I want only help here in how to manage threads from my main program

Let's say I launch 3 threads to monitor 3 ports.  My main program needs to know about them, and my main program or another thread may need to pass them information.  

Martin, I've read about threadpools, and it didn't seem to fit what I want to do.